# JQuery show page after page load

Tags: jquery

i want to show page after page load and put a spinner.

I search on the web in order to do that and find jquery loading plugin but it's on the archive now. Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a css for custom block as

```
display:none;
```

and after page is completely loaded change this behaviour via JS

```
setAttribute('display', 'block')
```

But if JS is disabled block will still remain invisible.

PS: in some webservers there is an option not to load page content, until it is completely rendered, but this would  make users see empty pages, what is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading page by ajax, then show the div containing the spinner in the beginning of the ajax call and then in the success function display the page and hide the div containing the spinner.